# Publish to Azure Website fails for some Dlls with "Specified network name is no longer available"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am using VS2013 preview to deploy a simple MVC application to Azure. This worked for a while but now the deployment fails for some DLLs as shown below:

```
2>Publishing folder bin...
2>Unable to add 'bin/EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll' to the Web site.  The specified network name is no longer available (550).
2>Unable to add 'bin/Newtonsoft.Json.dll' to the Web site.  The specified network name is no longer available (550).
2>Unable to add 'bin/System.Web.Mvc.dll' to the Web site.  The specified network name is no longer available (550).
2>Unable to add 'bin/WebGrease.dll' to the Web site.  The specified network name is no longer available (550).
2>Publishing folder Content...
```

Has anyone come across this problem and know why this happens? All other DLLs and files make it across without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to publish the same project in VS2012. Therefore this is a bug in the version of the VS2013 preview that I was using.